# Angular JS and jQuery UI autocomplete feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to build an autocomplete feature using pure angular but unfortunately UI is a bit tough to handle. I started building it with jQuery UI.

Then I came across a Fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/sebmade/swfjT/light/

```
<div ng-app='MyModule'>
    <div ng-controller='DefaultCtrl'>
        <input auto-complete ui-items="names" ng-model="selected">
        selected = {{selected}}
    </div>
</div>



function DefaultCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["john", "bill", "charlie", "robert", "alban", "oscar", "marie", "celine", "brad", "drew", "rebecca", "michel", "francis", "jean", "paul", "pierre", "nicolas", "alfred", "gerard", "louis", "albert", "edouard", "benoit", "guillaume", "nicolas", "joseph"];
}

angular.module('MyModule', []).directive('autoComplete', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            iElement.autocomplete({
                source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
                select: function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                      iElement.trigger('input');
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
    };
});
```

I want to show the options only after user has entered 3 valid characters.

Thanks,
Ankit Tanna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `minLength` option:

```
iElement.autocomplete({
    source: scope[iAttrs.uiItems],
    minLength: 3,
    select: function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          iElement.trigger('input');
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. This worked. :) I was not aware of the options.

Comment: This is the proper solution :)